# Getting an undefined value when I try to get data from a label

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a label where I try to get the Data in a variable. When I try to use this, I get an error because the type and the value are `undefined`.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="input-group date" input-type="date" id="startDate">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.startDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })


document.getElementById('description').onchange = function () {
    var startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
    var endDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value;
    var startDate_ms = startDate.getTime();
    var endDate_ms = endDate.getTime();
    var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
    var diff = Math.round(Math.abs((endDate_ms - startDate_ms) / (oneDay)));
    document.getElementById('description').value = diff.value;
}
```

Comment: `getElementById('description')` --> There is no element with le  `id="description"`.

Comment: It would be better if you can put HTML and JS in  a single snippet.

Comment: there's no "label" in any of your code. The `@Html.EditorFor` is using some templating language I'm not familiar with

Comment: @Anurag I did it

Comment: @chiliNUT It's ASP.NET MVC

Comment: then you should tag it that way

Comment: @chiliNUT I did it

Comment: You have a `<div>` with `id="startDate"` and you also have an `<input>` with ` `id="startDate"` which is invalid html, and `document.getElementById('startDate')` will only ever get the first one, and a `<div>` does not have a `value`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a label on your page with the id = 'description' you can't really use the onchange event on the label. have a look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

> The change event is fired for input, select, and textarea  elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each change to an element's value.

and even if you can rplace the label with an input you will not be able to use the change event as the change must happen by the user not by your code.

> when a change to the element's value is committed by the user.

So, I suggest if you are using JQuery to have a look at [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)
and here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xmhkt99/3/)

```
<button>Change Label</button>
<label id="description"> some value here </label>

$("button").on('click',function(){
     $("#description").text("Value changed").trigger("lblChanged");
});
$("#description").on('lblChanged', function(){
    console.log($("#description").text());
    // Write your code here
});
```

If you are using vanilla Javascript then have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)